# View Controllers and Multiple Views

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I'm working on my first iOS app and am trying to understand something about Views and View Controllers.

My question is this:  In an App like Instagram there's an 'Activity' tab in the main `Tab Bar Controller`.  The activity tab has a `UISegmentedControl` for "Following" & "You" which display similar data, but query different records.  Would the data in each of these `UISegments` be controlled by a separate controller? (`FollowingController` and `YouController`, for example).

What about instances like viewing locations on a Map, and you want to have a Map view and a List view?  Would there be a `MapViewController` and a `ListViewController`, or would one View Controller manage all of this, and different views would be loaded conditionally based on what the user selects?

Comment: You can implement container view controller, and simply load the views of view controllers in that. There is no need to have another view controller for map, you can put evrything in just one view controller !! IF you think the map part is called from some other class, then you might need to have a separate controller for map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you could use a single UIViewController and/or UITableView (depending on how you would like to present your data) and just change the `dataSource` based on Segmented Control's option.

For more information, please check [UITableViewDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/) for instance. In case of Table View, dataSource is nothing else than an array of some data.

Another approach besides Table View / Collection View would be to put `Container View` in UIViewController which would use just a single UIViewController instance. For more information [refer to the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html). Especially, take a look at the picture:

[image: Taken from Apple Documentation.]

For your second question - no again. You can have a single UIViewController and place instances of `MapKit` and/or list (aka `UITableView`). You can do that in Storyboard by dragging an instance of MapKit like this:

[image]

And your **single** UIViewController might look like this:

[image]

Comment: thanks for that response.  That makes sense to me for the first example because the views would be identical.  However in my second example, one would be a Table View, and the other would be a google map.  Would that then require two different view controllers?

Comment: thanks.  And then I would just hide / display those Table / Map views accordingly?

Comment: You can do whatever you want :) You can hide map and display tableView only or the other way around. If you wanted to implement clicking on the cell in order to show certain pin on the map you could do that as well. But in that case you might want to consider creating another UIViewController to handle this as you may want to display a map and some other informations below and not use tableView there at all. It's all a matter of what exactly do you want di achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like inheritance to the rescue here.

If you have a UISegmentedControl for "Following" and another UISegmentedControl for "You" then it there is the possibility that the best architecture will be to use inheritance and have two separate controllers for each of those UISegmentedControls, with names `FollowingSegmentedViewController` and `YouSegmentedViewController`, this way your separate controllers know the type of data they are loading and working with ("You" data or "Following" data) and other special considerations or differences between your "You" UIView and your "Following UIView like one being a map and one being a table.

And then for common UISegmentedControl functions and properties you have a base class that both your `FollowingSegmentedViewController` and `YouSegmentedViewController` **inherit** from, call it `BaseSegmentedViewController` or whatever is appropriate for your app and archiecture.

This inheritance allows you to share common UI elements (via @outlets) and other methods/functions between  `FollowingSegmentedViewController` and `YouSegmentedViewController` but then also address differences between the two specifically in their distinct controllers.